# Fine-Uploader: extraButtons.element allows only ID, but not CLASS

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using the Fine-Uploader plugin with some extra defined buttons as per the documentation here:

http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/extra-buttons.html

Here is my code:

```
$gallery_upload.fineUploaderS3({
...

extraButtons: [{
    element: $(".pdf-button"),
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ["jpg"]
    }
}],
...
```

Basically, it works pretty much as expected, except for one point.  Please note that I have specified the "element" as a jquery **"class"** called ".pdf-button".  The example in the documentation is an **"id"**.

When I used class, it means I'll be placing multiple buttons sharing the same class into my page.  However, it seems like only one button gets captured, and initialized as a Fine-Uploader upload a file button.

The rest stays as it is.

I was wondering if this is an expected behavior, and if so, would there be alternatives to achieve the behavior I'm trying to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Cheers,
Thomas

**[ Update ]**

According to conversation with Ray, I'm actually using this incorrectly.

You cannot expect FineUploader to be iterating over the jquery object on either FineUploader versions (with and without the JQuery wrapper). You would have to first build something like this:

```
var myExtraButtons = [
    {
        element: $('.file-trigger')[0]
    },
    {
        element: $('.file-trigger')[1]
    }
];
```

and then passing this into the Fine Uploader options like this:

```
$('fu-instance').fineUploaderS3({
    ...
    extraButtons: myExtraButtons,
    ...
});
```

The above is working for me now.

For details, see this discussion:
https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is not expected behavior.  You should file a bug if you are sure that the jquery object you have passed contains more than on element (at the time you create it).  If you are sure your jquery object contains multiple objects when it is created, and fine Uploader is only picking up the first in this instance, as a workaround, you'll need to include an array with a reference to each element in your case.  Quite frankly, I'd advise against using the jquery plugin wrapper.  It offers no real benefit.  The non-jquery syntax is much more intuitive.

Also, I would be very surprised if this is a bug in the library as the jquery wrapper code has not changed for a very long time, so you'll want to be absolutely sure that the jquery object you have passed contains multiple elements.

Comment: Hi Ray, it does seem like a bug then in that case.  I've created a JSFiddle.  I'm not doing anything dynamic, just placing a few html tags.  I'll try to file a bug on this.  [JSFiddle]I(http://jsfiddle.net/beamstyle_thomas/fyp5dqwt/3/).  I'm interested in knowing your advice about not using the jquery wrapper though.  Would that solve the problem by not using the jquery wrapper?  As a lot of examples out there are based on JQuery, I used that and seems like the code just becomes neater and shorter.  So I wasn't sure.  Would it be simple to port it back to the non-jquery version?

Comment: By the way one more thing.  You advised as a workaround to pass in an array with a reference to each element.  But actually, for the extraButtons.element option, it does not accept an array of elements.  It's not in the documentation, and it doesn't work when I do that either.

Comment: Regarding the jquery wrapper, please read https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310.

Comment: Hi Ray, this bug on multiple elements seem to exist even on the non-Jquery version.  I've generally got that ported over, but still happening.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've updated the answer to explain a bit more in details according to your solution during our conversation.